# AnimatePresence and react-router-dom [BrowserRouter] is not a <Route> component. All component of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, framer-motion

[BrowserRouter] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a  or <React.Fragment>

I don't understand why this isn't working anymore.
I've built a couple of apps with this folder structure - react-router-dom@6.0.3, and suddenly this stopped working.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-fire-54s0z9?file=/src/App.js) with my folder structure.

App.js

```
import './App.scss';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom'
import AnimatedRoutes from './Routes/AnimatedRoutes'
import Navbar from './Layouts/Navbar/Navbar'

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Navbar />
    <Router>
      <AnimatedRoutes />
    </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

AnimatedRoutes.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Homepage from '../Pages/Homepage/Homepage'
import ProjectPage from '../Pages/ProjectPage/ProjectPage'
import {BrowserRouter as Route, Routes, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom'
import { AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion'

function AnimatedRoutes() {

  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter
      onExitComplete={() => {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
          window.scrollTo({ top: 0 })
        }
      }}>
      <Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
        <Route path='/' element={<Homepage />} />
        <Route path='/:id' element={<ProjectPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
}

export default AnimatedRoutes;
```

HomePage.js

```
import React from 'react'

function Homepage() {

  return (
    <div className='homepage'>
      Homepage
    </div>
  );
}

export default Homepage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in line 4 of `AnimatedRoutes.js`, it should be

`import { Route, Routes, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom'`

There is an actual `<Route />` component that you should use, instead of `BrowserRouter as Route` that's already used once in `App.js`

Comment: I find it weird, because on other projects I imported it `Browser Router as Router`  and it worked.
Good to know.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nice, btw in `App.js` it's completely correct to use `{BrowserRouter as Router}` because you needed the **BrowserRouter** component (aka the **Router**,
but for `AnimatedRoutes.js` you needed just the **Route** component. because it's already wrapped inside a **Router** component in the **App** component